# How to configure Postfix to send specific error code for a domain?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I need to configure Postfix to send `451 4.7.0 Temporary problem, please try again later` for a specific domain.

I have tried to google for returning custom error codes for a domain with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the domain and desired text to [`access`](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html).

For example:

```
example.com 451 4.7.0 Temporary problem, please try again later
```

Remember to run `postmap` on it after editing it and reload Postfix.